# Can't mark specific folder in all subfolders in dired mode

Tags: dired

Emacs 26.1
Windows 10,
Dired

1. Show content of folder "**myproject**". All files and subfolders.
2. `M-x dired-maybe-insert-subdir (C-u i) -R`
   and here result

[image]

Nice.

Now I want to mark only folder **build**

1. `%m`
2. `^build$`

But I get  message:

```
0 matching files marked
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You want to match all files whose relative file names (no directory part) match `^build$`. The answer, in the version of `dired+.el` that you have, is to use a negative prefix arg. That's the short answer, for the version you have, but please read on.

---

The Dired+ command didn't correspond to the doc string (which was correct), concerning what the regexp is matched against.  I've fixed that now.

In the version before the fix, as just mentioned, you needed to use a negative prefix arg (e.g. `M--`) to match against only the relative file-name part (no directory part).

Now (after the fix) that's the default behavior, just as the doc string said - no prefix arg (to mark) or a plain prefix arg (`C-u`, to unmark) means match against the *relative* file name.

---

In any case, there's a lot of functionality (controlled by the prefix arg) that's rolled into **`% m`** (command `dired-mark-files-regexp`), so it can be confusing.

`C-h f` tells you:

> **`dired-mark-files-regexp`** is an interactive Lisp function in
>   [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> `(dired-mark-files-regexp REGEXP &optional MARKER-CHAR LOCALP)`
>
> Mark all file names matching `REGEXP` for use in later commands.
>
> `.` and `..` are never marked or unmarked by this command.
>
> Whether to mark or unmark, and what form of file name to match, are
>   governed by the prefix argument.  For this, a plain (`C-u`) or a
>   double-plain (`C-u C-u`) prefix arg is considered only as such - it is
>   not considered numerically.
>
> *Whether* to mark or unmark:
>
> - No prefix arg, a positive arg, or a negative arg means mark.
> - Plain (`C-u`), double-plain (`C-u C-u`), or zero (e.g. `M-0`) means
>     unmark.
>
> The form of a file name used for *matching*:
>
> - No prefix arg (to mark) or a plain prefix arg (`C-u`, to unmark)
>     means use the *relative* file name (no directory part).
> - A negative arg (e.g. `M--`, to mark) or a zero arg (e.g. `M-0`, to
>     unmark) means use the *absolute* file name, that is, including all
>     directory components.
> - A positive arg (e.g. `M-+`, to mark) or a double plain arg (`C-u C-u`, to unmark) means construct the name relative to
>     `default-directory`.  For an entry in an inserted subdir listing,
>     this means prefix the relative file name (no directory part) with
>     the subdir name relative to `default-directory`.
>
> Note that the default matching behavior of this command is different
>   for [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) than it is for vanilla Emacs.  Using a positive prefix arg
>   or a double plain prefix arg (`C-u C-u`) gives you the same behavior
>   as vanilla Emacs (marking or unmarking, respectively): matching
>   against names that are relative to the `default-directory`.
>
> What Dired+ offers in addition is the possibility to match against
>   names that are relative (have no directory part - no prefix arg or
>   `C-u` to mark and unmark, respectively) or absolute (`M--` or `M-0`,
>   respectively).
>
> The default behavior uses relative names because this
>   is likely to be the more common use case.  But matching against
>   absolute names gives you more flexibility.
>
> `REGEXP` is an Emacs regexp, not a shell wildcard.  Thus, use `\.o$`
>   for object files -- just `.o` might mark more than you might expect.
>
> `REGEXP` is added to `regexp-search-ring`, for regexp search.
>
> Non-interactively:
>
> - `MARKER-CHAR` is the marker character - used for `dired-marker-char`.
> - `LOCALP` is passed to `dired-get-filename`.  It determines the form of
>     filename that is matched against `REGEXP`.

Comment: I'm not found new version of dired+ package in MELPA. When I can download and how install it? Thanks

Comment: None of my libraries are on MELPA anymore. [MELPA no longer pulls from Emacs Wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7vocqa/update_on_melpa_removing_emacswiki_packages_they/dtuhzmt/). The library is here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el. (And there are two links to it in the answer.)

Comment: I never download file not from MELPA. So to install dired+ I need: 1. Download dired+.el from here https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el  to my custom Emacs folder (~/.emacs.d/elpa/dired+) , 2. In my init.el add (setq diredp-file "~/.emacs.d/elpa/dired+/dired+.el")
(load diredp-file). Is it correct? Or has more simple approach to install dired+ ?

Comment: Download `dired+.el`. Byte-compile it (`B` in Dired). Put `dired+.el` and `dired+.elc` in a directory that is in your [`load-path`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html): `(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/your/lisp/libraries")`. Add `(require 'dired+)` to your init file.  So your init file will contain code adding `"/path/to/your/lisp/libraries/"` to variable `load-path`, followed by `(require 'dired+)`.